# My XSLT file doesnt make a proper HTML file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am an amateur and have started XML and XSLT recently. 
I've been asked to make a XSLT file from the below XML.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <event>
 <title>Test 1</title>
 <description>The first test</description>
 <location>
<postalcode>A1A 1A1</postalcode>
<city>Vancouver</city>
<province>BC</province>
<streetaddress>Arina street east</streetaddress>
 </location>
 <attendees>
<name>John</name>
<email>example@gmail.com</email>
<phone>778777777</phone>
 </attendees>
 </event>
```

I made this XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- event.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
   <head><title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title></head>
 <body>
 <xsl:apply-templates />
 </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="event">
 <h2><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h2>
 <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="description">
 <p><xsl:value-of select="description"/></p>
 <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="location">
 <p>
<xsl:value-of select="streetaddress"/>
<xsl:value-of select="city"/>
<xsl:value-of select="province"/>
<xsl:value-of select="postalcode"/> 
</p>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attendees">
<xsl:for-each select="event/attendees">
<p>
<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="email"/>
<xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
</p>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is the generated HTML

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16">
   <title></title></head>
  <body>
   <h2>Test 1</h2>
     Test 1
   <p></p>The first test
   <p>Arina street eastVancouverBCA1A 1A1</p>
   A1A 1A1
   Vancouver
   BC
   Arina street east

John
example@gmail.com
778777777
 </body>
 </html>
```

this the desired html that I am looking for

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test 1</title>
<body>
<h2>Test 1</h2>
<p>The first test</p>
<p>
Ariana Street East<br>
Vancouver<br>
BC , A1A 1A1<br>
</p>
<!-- repeat-->
<p>
Name:john<br>
Email:example@gmail.com<br>
Phone:77877777
</p>

<p>
Name:john2<br>
Email:example2@gmail.com<br>
Phone:77877778
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

when I make a HTML file it is kind of messed up.
would you let me know where are my mistakes?
do you have any easy explained article?
 thank you

Comment: What does "kind of messed up" mean? What do you want your HTML to look like?

Comment: I added the html source too

Comment: Can you add what you want the HTML to look like?

Comment: I added the desired HTML too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this slightly adapted version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- event.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="event/title"/>
                </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title" />

    <xsl:template match="event">
        <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="location">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="streetaddress"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:value-of select="province"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:value-of select="postalcode"/>
            <br/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attendees">
        <p>
            Name: <xsl:value-of select="name"/><br/>
            Email: <xsl:value-of select="email"/><br/>
            Phone: <xsl:value-of select="phone"/><br/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Test 1</h2>

        <p></p>
        <p>Arina street east<br>Vancouver<br>BC<br>A1A 1A1<br></p>
        <p>
                        Name: John<br>
                        Email: example@gmail.com<br>
                        Phone: 778777777<br></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in "attendess" pattern match:

```
<xsl:template match="attendees">
    <xsl:for-each select="event/attendees"> 
    <p>...
```

The "for-each" instruction is redundant, attendees template is applied from de "apply-templates" instruction in the event template.

The first title section wont work, update it to:

```
<title><xsl:value-of select="event/title"/></title>
```

add field names at the begining and 
 elements at the end of the lines on attendees and location

```
<xsl:template match="location">
    <p>
        address:<xsl:value-of select="streetaddress"/><br> 
        city:<xsl:value-of select="city"/><br> 
        province:<xsl:value-of select="province"/><br> 
        postalcode:<xsl:value-of select="postalcode"/> <br> 
    </p>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I changed it but it didnt help too much

Comment: You should add <br> tags at the end of the fields you want to output in attendees and location templates.
It's very misterious why you are obtaining the event title 2 times.